# How to update headers before launch emit?

Tags: socket.io

Every time, when I create socket, I pass headers with Token in it

**socket.js**

```
const headers = { 
  Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("access_token")}`,
};
const socket = io(HOST, { extraHeaders: headers });
export default socket;
```

But when access_token becomes obsolete, I have to refresh page to create new socket. Is there any ability to update headers without reinitiating socket?

I've tried this function, but it didn't work:

```
updateSocketHeaders() {
    const headers = getNewHeaders();
    this.io.opts.extraHeaders = headers;
  }
```